# Flag Answer button not enabled properly on dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, flagging

When you select 'other' without entering anything into the text box and then click 'not an answer', the Flag Answer button is not enabled.

Clicking 'not an answer' again properly enables the button.

(I am using Firefox 5.0 on Windows 7)

Comment: This has been [reported on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99882/flag-a-question-dialog-bug), thanks for re-acknowledging this! We'll return with a resolution once one happens. ♪

Comment: The item on Meta Stack Overflow seems to be Status-Completed.  Could you please update it here also?

Comment: Are you still experiencing the issue?

Comment: No.  It seems to be fixed now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed back on August 22nd, [thanks to Jarrod Dixon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99882/flag-a-question-dialog-bug/103467#103467). ♪

Flagging should work normally from now on, no more button disabling.